# How to receive correlated msg from MsgBox in BizTalk

Tags: biztalk, correlation

I have the following piece of orchestration:

[image]

I send a message to a web service, it answers me with some dummy msg. Then it sends me another useful msg (the Receive shape in the *Get actual answer from the service* group has **Following Correlation Sets** which is initialized in the Send shape) and I should response back.

Everything works fine if I use 'Specify later' binding for the `ServiceAnswerPort`. But when I choose to use msgbox-direct-binding I get exception saying that now I have multiple subscribers and thus I'm unable to send a message thru the Send shape. What are the ways to make it work?

Comment: What's your correlation set? Does error occure when one orchestration is working or multiple of them? And do you mean the first send shape sending request or the next one sending response?

Comment: Correlation set is built up from an element of the message schema, `RequestId` which is a Guid. The error occurs even if only one orchestration is working. The fist send shape causes the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using solicit-response (two way) port, the biztalk engine expects that for every message sent from the port, one response message will arrive back. At runtime, when sending the message from solicit-response port, biztalk is checking how many recipients there are to the message, and if more then one is found the error you get occurs. usually this is solved by adding a filer the recipients making sure a message cannot be accepted by more then one of them.